# Wordpress SSO плагин SAML 2 после авторизации на сайте куда нужно редирект поставить?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress SSO plagin SAML 2 после авторизации на другом сайте куда нужно редирект поставить и какие данные отправить каким методом?

Comment: Попробуй исправить вопрос,  но в этот разу уже что бы было по-русски.

Comment: @SeVlad ТС решил, что лучше завести другой акк и спросить на SO eng: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263767/wordpress-sso-plug-in-saml-2-after-authorization-on-the-site-where-you-need-to-s

Comment: @KAGGDesign :))) Нда.. Но я не уверен, что гуглоперевод исправит ситуацию